# SelectionChanged for DataGrid is being called multiple times after changing screen in conductor

Tags: wpf, event-handling, caliburn.micro

We've a conductor with two screens being displayed alternatively. Screen 1 has `DataGrid` which is attached with a method in ViewModel using ActionMessage for `SelectionChanged` event. Screen 2 has very basic UI. We change the screen by setting ActiveItem property of conductor on some event. Screen 1 is default for conductor and it works fine on load.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers> 
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged"> 
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="test_SelectionChanged" >   
            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=grdTest, Mode=OneTime}">
            </cal:Parameter> 
        </cal:ActionMessage> 
    </i:EventTrigger> 
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And in ViewModel:

```
public void test_SelectionChanged(object param) { //code }
```

Problem is that `SelectionChanged` for DataGrid is being called multiple(like 3 times if I set viewmodel to ActiveItem thrice) times after changing the screens. It seems to me like event subscribers are being added for SelectionChanged whenever screen 1’s viewmodel is set to ActiveItem.

Could you please help and let me know how to avoid the situation?

Comment: what is the code which subscribe a handler to the `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: Hi,

Please find below code.

View - 

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="test_SelectionChanged"  >
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=grdTest, Mode=OneTime}"></cal:Parameter>
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

ViewModel -
public void test_SelectionChanged(object param)
        {
//code

}